# Automatically adjust Jtable Column to fit content

Tags: java, swing, jtable, preferredsize, tablecolumn

I am trying to match the JTable column width depending on the data inside. My Code:

```
    for(int column = 0; column < gui.testsuiteInfoTable.getColumnCount(); column ++){
        int  width =0;
    for (int row = 0; row < gui.testsuiteInfoTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
         TableCellRenderer renderer = gui.testsuiteInfoTable.getCellRenderer(row, column);
         Component comp = gui.testsuiteInfoTable.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
         width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
         System.out.println(width);
     }
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn();
    col = gui.testsuiteInfoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    System.out.println(width);
    col.setWidth(width);
    gui.testsuiteInfoTable.revalidate();

    }
}
```

The sizes are correct I guess but the table columns still all have the same width! The table is embedded in a ScrollPane in a GridBagLayout is that the problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Look at [link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can use an extra library, try Swingx (https://java.net/projects/swingx)
There you have a JXTable, with a method "packAll()", that does exactly what you are asking for

Answer (score 25):

This is all you need:

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
    @Override
       public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
           Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
           int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
           TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
           tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth + getIntercellSpacing().width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
           return component;
        }
    };
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

The table will adjust each column width automatically to fit the content. There's no need to control when to trigger the resizing.

Comment: That'll works, but you'll get a warning asking for serialVersionUID if you don't add it. +1.

Comment: It looks like once the table column gets resized to a larger value, it doesn't shrink back down to fit the current state of columns.

Answer (score 6):

```
col.setWidth(width);
```

Read the JTable API and follow the link on `How to Use Tables`. In that tutorial they use the `setPreferredWidth(...)` to suggest a width for a column.

You may also want to check out the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) which does this for you. This solution can also take into account the width of the column header.

Comment: Thank you. The problem seems to be if you don´t add the JTable to a JScrollPane, then setWidth etc. does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my solution:

```
public class AutoResizedTable extends JTable {
    {
        setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        super.tableChanged(e);
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void doLayout() {
        for(int column = 0; column < getColumnCount(); column ++){
            int  width = getParent().getWidth();
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component comp = prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
            }
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn();
            col = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            col.setPreferredWidth(width);
        }
        super.doLayout();
    }
}
```